# Rewrite scalar UDF to table UDF or insert UDF in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

In my stored procedure, I have a temporary table which was created to increase performance.

With the actual select statement in the stored procedure, several scalar UDF's were used and the temp table replaces them:

```
INSERT INTO #BEDRAGEN
    SELECT 
        DD.ColumnA, DD.ColumnB, DD.ColumnC, 
        ISNULL(DBO.SIF_get_SalesAmount(DD.ColumnA, DD.ColumnB, DD.ColumnC), 0) AS Totaalbedrag,
    FROM 
        T_InvoiceDetailDosDet as IDD
```

My question is: I want to replace `dbo.SIF_get_SalesAmount` with code or make the scalar UDF a tabled one if that will increase performance.

What is in this UDF:

Returns an amount.

It reads an file and calculates several things before resulting in an total.

Function has 3 parameters going in and Amount going out.

Piece of UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SIF_get_SalesAmountDosDetail] 
    (@A VARCHAR(20),
     @B VARCHAR(20),
     @C VARCHAR(20) 
    )
RETURNS NUMERIC(12,2)
AS
    DECLARE @SalesAmount NUMERIC(12,2)
    ,       @SalesUnitOfAccount TINYINT
    ,       @Unit NCHAR(5)
    ,       @SalesUnit NCHAR(5)
    ,       @TotalUnits  NUMERIC(15, 3)

    SELECT        
        @unit = p.Unit,
        @SalesUnit = p.SalesUnit,
        @SalesUnitOfAccount = dd.SalesUnitOfAccount
    FROM 
        dbo.T_table p
    WHERE
        p.ColumnA = @A AND p.ColumnB = @B AND p.ColumnC = @C

    SELECT @rc = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @rc <> 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SalesAmount = 0
        RETURN @SalesAmount
    END

    IF @SalesUnit = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SalesUnit = 1
    END

    -- several calculations follow based on values of @Unit etc.
    --  at the end of the UDF:
    --  last if then else calculation and then returning the Amount.
    IF @SalesUnitOfAccount = 4
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PricePerDesc = @SalesUnit
        SELECT @SalesAmount = CONVERT(numeric(12, 2), round((@CurrPrice * (@TotalSalesUnits / @SalesComputQty)) - @DiscAmount, 2))
    END

    SELECT @TotalSalesAmount = @TotalSalesAmount + ISNULL(@SalesAmount, 0)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @TotalSalesAmount
```

What way could I insert this UDF-code in my stored procedure select? Or what way could I make it a UDF_table function?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes, replacing calls to scalar UDFs with the body of the UDF, or turning the UDF into an inline table-valued UDF will normally greatly increase performance. If you are able to convert the entire logic of your UDF into a single `select` statement, you can give it a shot. There is no point to convert it to a multi-step table-valued UDF.

Comment: Thanks. But I have no clue how to put this logic with all the cases and calculations into a single select statement which is a subselect for filling the #temp table. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are many ways and they all depend on exactly what you are doing. I would start by defining a CTE in the form of `with base_data as (SELECT p.Unit, case when p.SalesUnit = 0 then 1 else p.SalesUnit end as SalesUnit, dd.SalesUnitOfAccount FROM dbo.T_table p WHERE p.ColumnA = @A AND p.ColumnB = @B AND p.ColumnC = @C) select * from base_data`, make it return other calculated columns as needed (e.g. `case when dd.SalesUnitOfAccount = 4 then round((CurrPrice * (TotalSalesUnits / SalesComputQty)) - DiscAmount, 2) end`, relying on previously added calculated columns), then `select` from that.

Comment: Thx I will give it a try. Very new to SQL so struggling.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is exactly the focus of a recently announced feature in SQL Server 2019 (CTP2.1 onwards) called "[Scalar UDF Inlining](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/11/07/introducing-scalar-udf-inlining/)". This feature works by automatically embedding (or inlining) the logic of a UDF into the calling query. You could give it a try by downloading it for free.

If you want to know how it works behind the scenes, the details can be found in a recent research paper “[Froid: Optimization of Imperative programs in a Relational Database](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol11/p432-ramachandra.pdf)“. That paper describes a systematic approach to express entire UDFs as SQL, which you can use. The Scalar UDF inlining feature is based on Froid, and can result in huge performance gains in many cases.

[Disclosure: I am a co-author of the Froid paper]

Comment: Indeed that would be a nice feature. 
But SQL2019 is not going to be implemented here in a long time.
Stuck with 2012 version for a while.